# Checking for lists of empty values

Tags: python, empty-list

What is the most effective way to check if a list contains only empty values (not if a list is empty, but a list of empty elements)? I am using the famously pythonic implicit booleaness method in a for loop:

```
def checkEmpty(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if element:
            return False
            break
    else:
        return True
```

Anything better around?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if not any(lst):
    # ...
```

Should work.  `any()` returns `True` if any element of the iterable it is passed evaluates `True`.  Equivalent to:

```
def my_any(iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        if i:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Seems to be the most elegant approach :-)

Comment: I agree, this is nice and clean.

Answer (score 3):

```
len([i for i in lst if i]) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `all`:

```
   if all(item is not None for i in list):
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: I think `all`'s brother `any` feels slighted.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I like the shorter approach using any, but I thought I would throw in my two cents for an alternate idea.

Comment: Depending on the OP's definition of "empty", `not bool(item)` may be better than `item is not None`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks for the edit, you can change whatever you find to be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['', '', '', '']
>>> bool([_ for _ in l if _])
False
>>> l = ['', '', '', '', 1]
>>> bool([_ for _ in l if _])
True
```

Comment: This is a bit awkward looking and it doesn't short circuit like `not any(l)`.

Comment: I agree that this solution is far from optimal :)